# UDP java not sending full string

Tags: java, udp, send

I'm doing a simple voting System using java and UDP. Where I have three computers, one computer is the server, one adds the candidates and the other one is used for voting. Sending the candidates and adding them to the server is working ok, but whenever I have to send the candidates data to the third computer my string is never fully received. Each candidate is stored in an object where I store the name[String] and votes[int] of each candidate, and all of that is stored in an arraylist.

```
InetAddress IPres = InetAddress.getByName(IPresimp);
String name = candidate.get(pos).name;
String posi = Integer.toString(pos);
String candidate = name.concat(":" +posi);
set = new DatagramPacket(candidate.getBytes(), 0, candidaate.getBytes().length, IPres, get.getPort());
socket.send(set);
```

I'm sending it like this so whenever I send the name of the candidate to the third computer I also send the position I'm currently evaluating, so for example I should be sending something like "Obama:2". But whenever I receive the package I only get "Obama", anything I add to the string is never sent.

Receiving code:

```
try {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[400];
    get = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    socket.receive(get);
    String info = new String(get.getData());
    System.out.println(info);
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: This data is too short to be truncated as you describe in sending. The problem is in the receiving code.

Comment: what do you mean? here is how I'm receiving the data                    
           `try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[400];
            get = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            socket.receive(get);
            String info = new String(get.getData());
            System.out.println(info);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } `

Comment: It is probably Russian hackers trying to rig your election :-)

Comment: What do you mean what do I mean? What part of 'the 'problem is in the receiving code' didn't you understand?

Answer (score 2):

```
String info = new String(get.getData());
```

The problem is here, in the receiving code. It should be:

```
    String info = new String(get.getData(), get.getOffset(), get.getLength());
```

At present you are ignoring the actual length of the `DatagramPacket`, and assuming it filled the buffer, and filling the `String` full of rubbish.